# How to enter input to the code while debugging the code in the vs code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, debugging, input, terminal

How can we enter input to the code while debugging the code in the vs code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMXos.png)

I cant even enter the input in debug console or terminal.Please suggest go head. my bebug hangs on after the scanf

Solution to enter the input to the code while debugging my code in the vs code

Answer (score 0):

Go to view then terminal, then press 'Run and Debug' button or press 'F5' once the program stops executing you can now enter the input and you can finally continue.